# How to get current Vaadin Theme name?

Tags: java, user-interface, vaadin, vaadin7

I am using the `@Theme` annotation in Vaadin to set UI themes. How can I get this theme name in any view? Is there some sort of `getTheme()` method I can use?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Vaadin API](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html#getTheme()) and in most cases: `UI.getCurrent().getTheme()`. Otherwise, eg: you're executing some background thread, you need to find a way to get hold of your `UI` instance.